# How can I force one to one relationship on SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, sql-server-2008-r2, one-to-one

Here is my scenario on *SQL Server 2008 R2*:

This is my first table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foos](
    [FooId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Foos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [FooId] ASC
  )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the second table which has a relationship to `Foos` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bars](
    [BarId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FooId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [BarId] ASC
  )
) ON [PRIMARY]

Go

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bars]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bars_Foos] FOREIGN KEY([FooId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Foos] ([FooId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

But it is not one to one. What should I do to force this to be `one to one` relationship? Should I use check constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique constraint to `FooId` in `Bars`.

However, you don't need `BarID` then because they have the same key. So it looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bars] (
    [FooId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Bars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FooId),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Bars_Foos] FOREIGN KEY([FooId]) 
           REFERENCES [dbo].[Foos] ([FooId])
           ON DELETE CASCADE
)
GO
```

However again, you don't need `Bars` at all: it is one table...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. One thing in my mind is if there is really a one to one relationship term or not. Let's say I am using an ORM tool and read the schema of the DB. would that ORM tool sees this a one to one rel? I know it depends on the tool but is there a common sense?

Comment: @tugberk: I have seen Hibernate create extra tables that are unnecessary. Common sense is to define the model/design in the database independently of what the ORM says. But that's my opinion as a database guy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `Identity column(BarID)` also. Then [Unique key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) will help you out from this problem.

```
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT OBJECT_ID from sys.objects WHERE name ='foo_bars')
alter table bars add constraint foo_bars unique(fooid)
```